# Handling Loading Message in Dropdown using WebDriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver

There is a dropdown. Whenever I try to retrieve the values from the dropdown, I get the "Loading..." as one of the option in the dropdown. How do I put wait in the code so that it waits till the dropdown is completely populated with values.

I have used following code , but it does not work:

```
Boolean eleVendorId=false;
eleVendorId =
    new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
    .withTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .pollingEvery(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .until(new Function<WebDriver, Boolean>() {

        public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
            Boolean flag=false;
            List<WebElement> list_options=new Select(category).getOptions();
            for(WebElement temp:list_options){
                if(!temp.getText().contains("Loading")){
                    flag=true;
                }
            }
            return flag;
        }
    });
```

Still i get the output:

```
-All-
Loading ....
```

Comment: Can you share page `URL` or at least `HTML` of drop-down?

Comment: Just checked the HTML does not have Loading message. <select id="category" class="advanced-dropdown-category form-control category-dropdown" name="Category">
<option>-All-</option>
<option>Records</option>
</select>. The Loading message is coming from the javascript

Comment: Hmm... I think that it is simple `div` with visible/hidden toggle. You just need to find it

Comment: possibly try selecting the value using js. Something like ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("document.getElementById('category').value='displayedvalue'");

Answer (score 0):

You need to use web-driver method until.elementIsVisble(WebElement) http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/lib/until.html

Then you only need to wait until a "Loading..." element disappear.